# Pow function returning -NaN

Tags: c++, nan

So, when I try to calculate this operation, I get a NaN result.

```
double raz3 = pow(-64, 1.0/3);
```

It should return -4, but it returns -NaN instead.
I have thought that it was an overflow problem, so I changed the type to long long, instead I receive a value of -9223372036854775808

How can I make it return -4?

Comment: From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) : If base is finite and negative and exp is finite and non-integer, a domain error occurs and a range error may occur.

Comment: `1/3` can't be perfectly represented in binary system, same way as it can't be represented in decimal system. Can you tell me what is the result of: `(-64)^0.333333`?

Comment: @MarekR `0.333333` is also not perfectly represented by a `double`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux this is just an example showing the problem in human readable form.

Comment: TL;DR: Use [`std::cbrt`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/cbrt). Note that this still uses floating point math; there is no standard function that extracts the cube roots of integers for perfect cubes (because it would have to be undefined for almost all its inputs).

Comment: @MaxLanghof I cannot use a "static" root function. The full code would be ```double raz1 = uv / pv;
 double raz2 = vp - 1;
 double raz3 = pow(raz1, 1.0/raz2); ``` The values are inputs from the user, the function works fine, but fails with these values. Is there any way of fixing it?

Comment: @prepz I gave you the shortest answer that fixes your code, but the dupe has other, more general ways (which boil down to removing the sign beforehand and re-applying it afterwards - which would have to happen behind the scenes anyway).